# Rails nested resources ignore single route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a rails nested resource in my routing.

i.e

```
resources :users do
  resources :accounts
end

resources :accounts
```

The listing operations of course will be:

```
GET /users
GET /users/:user_id/accounts
```

I want to get rid of the `/users` route but retain the `/users/:id/accounts` route.

Any idea how I can go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let set `only: []` then rails routes will generate `/users/:id/accounts` as you want

```rb
resources :users, only: [] do
 resources :accounts # , only: [:index] if you just only keep users/:id/accounts
end
# if you only want to get rid of GET /users
resources :users, except: [:index]
# if you mean you want to get rid all of /users routes (not just only GET /users) then comment above line
```

Comment: Note that this will generate `/users/:user_id/accounts` and not `/users/:id/accounts` as per the conventions for [nested routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). If you REALLY want to break the conventions you would need to do  `scope 'users/:id', as: :user { resources :accounts }`

Answer (score 2):

Using `except: [:index]` not will restrict both routes. Thats a nonsenical claim that can easily be refuted by just running `rails routes`. None of the options for `resources` "trickle down" to nested calls.

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :accounts, only: :index
end
```

`only: []` skips generation of all the "user" routes.

This will generate the routes:

```
Prefix        Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
user_accounts GET    /users/:user_id/accounts(.:format)   accounts#index
# ...
```

Note that the param key is `:user_id` and not `:id`. If you REALLY want to break the conventions you would need to do:

```
# don't do this - its stupid
scope '/users/:id', as: :user do
  resources :accounts, only: :index
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and sorry for not being clear in my question. Glad you helped anyways. This is great!

Answer (score 0):

This is what `scope` is for

```rb
scope :users do 
  resources :accounts
end
```

[Rails guides on routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: That will generate `/users/accounts` and not  `/users/:id/accounts`. Admittedly though the question is very confused and its hard to tell what the author wants.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use these same two ways, use `namespace` with `scope`:

```
  namespace :users do
    scope ':user_id' do
      resources :accounts
    end
  end
```

Use just only `scope`:

```
  scope ':users/:user_id' do
    resources :accounts
  end
```

Comment: That will generate `/users/accounts` and not `/users/:id/accounts`.